# How to send parameters to mock function?

Tags: python, parameters, mocking, python-unittest

I have two functions. Function `function2()` call `function1()`.
Original `function1()` get one value from parameter and return one value. I want to test the `function2()` with mock `function1()`. But mock `function1()` not accepted parameter. Where is the problem?

Call a mock `function1()` without a parameter is not a problem. If I want to use the parameter, the test will end with an error.

> function1_mock() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parameter'.

```py
# application.py

def function1(parameter1):
    return parameter1

def function2(parameter2):
    return function1('function1') + parameter2
```

```py
# test_application.py

import unittest
import unittest.mock

import application


class TestCalling(unittest.TestCase):

    def function1_mock(self, parameter):
        return parameter

    @unittest.mock.patch('application.function1', side_effect=function1_mock)
    def test_function2(self, mock_function):
        self.assertEqual(application.function2('function2'),
                         'function1function2')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In this case in the test is error

> TypeError: function1_mock() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parameter'

I want write syntactically correct code, where mock function accept parameter.

Comment: You "overmocked". `@unittest.mock.patch('application.function1', return_value='function1')` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. I convert the method `function1_mock(self, parameter)` in the class `TestCalling()` to function `function1_mock(parameter)`. This works corectly. 
The complet code:

```py
# application.py

def function1(parameter1):
    print('o f1')
    return parameter1


def function2(parameter2):
    print('o f2')
    return function1('function11') + parameter2
```

```py
# test_application.py

import unittest
import unittest.mock

import application


class TestCalling(unittest.TestCase):

    def function1_mock(parameter):
        print('function1_mock')
        return parameter

    @unittest.mock.patch('application.function1', side_effect=function1_mock)
    def test_function2(self, mock_function):
        self.assertEqual(application.function2('function2'), 'function1function2')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

To DroidX86: thank's for hint.

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1_mock(self, parameter):
```

this function takes 2 params. the object `self` & `parameter`.

```
def function1(parameter1):
```

this mock expects only one. so when your code calls it, it passes only one param.

Try this:

```
 @unittest.mock.patch('application.function1', side_effect=self.function1_mock)
```

This will add the `self` parameter to the mock call

Remember: `obj.func()` is syntactic sugar for `__Classname__func(obj)`

Comment: The solution:```@unittest.mock.patch('application.function1', side_effect=self.function1_mock)``` is not correct, because produce following error: NameError: name 'self' is not defined.